# Autofac: any way to resolve the innermost scope?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, autofac

I'm currently trying out Autofac in a new ASP.NET MVC project after having used Ninject, Castle Windsor and other IoC containers in the last years. So while I know about IoC containers in general, I'm fairly new to Autofac and I'm still looking for some best practices.

Currently I'm trying to find out if there is a way to resolve the innermost nested scope.

I have the following situation: a component that is registered as SingleInstance() has a method that creates a nested lifetime scope, providing a configuration action to configure some components as InstancePerLifetimeScope, and within this nested scope resolves the registered components to do something useful, like so:

```
ILifetimeScope currentScope = ???;

using (var scope = currentScope.BeginLifetimeScope(cb => {
  cb.RegisterType<X>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
  // ...
}))
{
    var comp = scope.Resolve<X>();
    // ...
}
```

The issue is that I would like currentScope to be the innermost lifetime scope, because I know that X depends on components inside the innermost scope. In the simplest case that would be e.g. the current request lifetime scope. I can of course get it with AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.RequestLifetimeScope but I don't want to use that as it isn't really well testable. Also, that lifetime scope isn't necessarily the innermost.

So, is there a way to find the innermost lifetime scope given e.g. the root container or a different ILifetimeScope?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Autofac, the innermost scope is always the container. Using the AutofacDependencyResolver, it'd be
`AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.ApplicationContainer`

There is no way from a nested scope (if all you have is an `ILifetimeScope`) to "walk backward" to get to the container. I'm not necessarily sure you want to do that, anyway.

It sounds like your SingleInstance component is doing some sort of service location, basically, with manual registration/resolution of certain components. If the set of types being registered is fixed, I might recommend (if possible) some redesign of your system, so the SingleInstance component isn't registered as SingleInstance anymore and instead gets registered as InstancePerDependency, then have that take these other items in as constructor parameters.

Instead of...

```
// Consuming class like this...
public class BigComponent
{
  public void DoSomethingCool()
  {
    using(var scope = ...)
    {
      var c = scope.Resolve<SubComponent>();
      c.DoWork();
    }
  }
}

// ...and container registrations like this...
builder.RegisterType<BigComponent>().SingleInstance();
```

You might try inverting it a bit:

```
// Consuming class like this...
public class BigComponent
{
  private SubComponent _c;
  public BigComponent(SubComponent c)
  {
    _c = c;
  }
  public void DoSomethingCool()
  {
    _c.DoWork();
  }
}

// ...and container registrations like this...
builder.RegisterType<BigComponent>().InstancePerDependency();
builder.RegisterType<SubComponent>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

The idea is to not have to do the on-the-fly registration-and-immediate-resolution thing.

If you're stuck doing service location, you'll need to use `AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.ApplicationContainer` if you need the absolute innermost scope, but keep in mind any objects you register scoped to `InstancePerHttpRequest` will not be resolvable if you do that, so you could get into trouble. It really is recommended to use the `AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.RequestLifetimeScope` instead. That would make your method:

```
var requestScope = AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.RequestLifetimeScope;
using (var scope = requestScope.BeginLifetimeScope(cb => {
  cb.RegisterType<X>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
  // ...
}))
{
    var comp = scope.Resolve<X>();
    // ...
}
```

In a testing environment, the `AutofacDependencyResolver` lets you swap in the provider that dictates how request lifetimes get generated. You can implement a simple/stub one like this:

```
public class TestLifetimeScopeProvider : ILifetimeScopeProvider
{
    readonly ILifetimeScope _container;
    private ILifetimeScope _lifetimeScope = null;

    public TestLifetimeScopeProvider(ILifetimeScope container)
    {
        if (container == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
        _container = container;
    }

    public ILifetimeScope ApplicationContainer
    {
        get { return _container; }
    }

    public ILifetimeScope GetLifetimeScope()
    {
        if (_lifetimeScope == null)
        {
            _lifetimeScope = ApplicationContainer.BeginLifetimeScope("httpRequest")
        }
        return _lifetimeScope;
    }

    public void EndLifetimeScope()
    {
        if (_lifetimeScope != null)
            _lifetimeScope.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Again, just a stub for unit testing, not something you'd ever use in production.

Then when you wire up the `DependencyResolver` in your test, you provide your lifetime scope provider:

```
var lsProvider = new TestLifetimeScopeProvider(container);
var resolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container, lsProvider);
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(resolver);
```

This lets you use `InstancePerHttpRequest` and such inside unit tests without actually having a real request context. It also means you should be able to use the request lifetime scope in your registration/resolution method and not have to fall back on the application container.

Comment: The "BigComponent" in my case is a registry that holds certain objects for the whole life of the application. The nested scope is used during application startup (first HTTP request) to instantiate some types discovered dynamically (plugin architecture). My current solution is to inject a Func<ILifetimeScope> into the "BigComponent" that is currently registered as `()=>AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.RequestLifetimeScope`. Still not great, but it leaves the static reference to the service locator out of the scope. [continued]

Comment: BTW: with _innermost_ scope I meant the most deeply nested scope. For me, the application container is the _outermost_ scope.

Comment: My misunderstanding on reference to innermost/outermost, sorry. Either way, you can't really walk the stack in either direction, so if you have to do the service location, you're stuck with AutofacDependencyResolver. Note if you use MVC IDependencyResolver, then DependencyResolver.Current.GetService will always come out of the request lifetime, so you may not need that lambda... oh, except you're registering on the fly. So, yep, you'll still need that.

Comment: Generally speaking, I try to invert this stuff. If I have some application-level thing with cached objects, I'll take those objects as parameters into my plugins rather than vice-versa. Intentional design to avoid the service location, if you will. Sometimes it's unavoidable, but I can't help but think there's a "code smell" here you could address with a little refactoring.

Comment: Problably my example wasn't that great. What I try to achieve all happens during initialization to set up the container. I don't know the types of the components to register until runtime, so I can't resolve them statically. Instead, I register them dynamically and resolve them directly so that _their_ dependencies are nicely resolved without explicit service location. I'll be back on sunday with a better description of what I'm trying to do. Thanks so far already for your time. Probably it'll boil down to my Func<ILifetimeScope> approach, as I can't seem to get the innermost scope otherwise.

Comment: Is `AutofacDependencyResolver` available in Autofac 3.5.2? I can't seem to find a reference to it...

Comment: @SteveEynon It's in the Autofac.Mvc5 package. The core Autofac package doesn't have application-type-specific integration code. http://autofac.org/scriptgen/

Comment: @TravisIllig Ah yes, thanks. I didn't realise the question was ASP.NET based... I'm writing a console application, Is there anything similar available in the core Autofac package?

Comment: @SteveEynon The best place to start [is the documentation](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) - we have a whole [getting started guide](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/index.html) that uses a console app as an example.

Comment: @TravisIllig Thanks, I've already successfully created an application with Autofac, scoured the documentation and am using Lifetime Scopes. I am no stranger to IoCs (having written a popular IoC for the [Fantom](http://fantom.org/) language) but, like the OP, I cannot invert my logic and wish to get hold of the current Lifetime Scope and resolve from that. Is it possible with the core package?

Comment: You might need to create a new question with some additional context and provide some additional information about the challenge you're seeing. Given this question is pretty specific to MVC, it'll be helpful to see more context about your issue so an accurate and detailed answer can be provided rather than trying to answer it in a comment thread.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are searching for ASP.NET WebApi:

You can use `GetRequestLifetimeScope()` method of `AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver`.