# Autofac custom lifetime manager

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, lifetime

There is one possibility that I haven't found in Autofac. A custom lifetime manager.
For instance, in Windsor.Castle it's possible to write custom lifetime manager simply derived from `AbstractLifestyleManager`.

```
public class MyCustomLifestyleManager : AbstractLifestyleManager
{
 public overrid object Resolve(CreationContext context)
 {
 ...
 }

}
```

Does anybody know how to do that in autofac? I know about standart lifetime managers but the question is it possible to produce my own?

Comment: What lifestyle do you wish to add? In my experience it is very rare to need a real new lifestyle and most of them could be implemented by registering a delegate any way.

Comment: I commented this below. But I repeat :)  For instance, I want to register UI form like this - container.RegisterType<MyForm>().Singleton().ExternallyOwned() The form can be closed by user. Therefore I prefer something like this- (in Resolve function). if (myForm.IsDisposed) and in this case container produced NEW form. In other case - return form that was created before

Comment: @evgeniy.chepurnykh And the solution was..??

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd want to use a custom lifetime scope, see [the Autofac blog post](http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer/) about this.

> Autofac caters to units of work through lifetime scopes. A lifetime scope (`ILifetimeScope`) 
>   is just what it sounds like – a scope at the completion of which, the lifetime of a set of 
>   related components will end.
>
> Component instances that are resolved during the processing of a unit of work get associated 
>   with a lifetime scope. By tracking instantiation order and ensuring that dependencies can 
>   only be satisfied by components in the same or a longer-lived lifetime scope, Autofac can 
>   take responsibility for disposal when the lifetime scope ends.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433983/autofac-any-way-to-resolve-the-innermost-scope) provides example code.

Comment: This is not the same. For instance, I want to register UI form like this - container.RegisterType<MyForm>().Singleton().ExternallyOwned().

Comment: The form can be closed by user. Therefore I prefer something like this- (in Resolve function). if (myForm. IsDisposed) return null and in this case container produced NEW form. In other case - return form that was created before.

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement `ILifetimeScopeProvider` such as [RequestLifetimeScopeProvider](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/Core/Source/Autofac.Integration.Mvc/RequestLifetimeScopeProvider.cs).

Comment: Note this only exists in the Autofac MVC3 extensions. It can't be used with Autofac in general.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're in a web application, there's no easy way to implement your own custom lifestyle. Web apps have a lifetime scope provider (typically used for a request scope), but other apps don't.

As you noticed, the way to do custom things with your objects based on creation is using the OnActivated or OnActivating events. There is also an OnRelease that allows you to run your own custom logic at disposal time. But it would be up to you to implement your own extensions to make the mechanism look nice syntactically.

You can also register delegate expressions (lambdas) as dependencies so you could do some pretty fancy stuff there.

Between all those things, you should be able to accomplish what you're looking to do.