# Resource lifetime control issue

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac

I'm trying to find a way to manage the lifetime of a resource independent from the component that is using it. The following sample shows my approach. It's not yet working as intented, but it shows my intention.

```
class GlobalService
{
    static int instanceCounter = 0;
    public int instanceId = ++instanceCounter;
    public void DoWhatever() { }
}

class Consumer
{
    private readonly Func<Owned<GlobalService>> _globalServiceFactory;
    public Consumer(Func<Owned<GlobalService>> globalServiceFactory)
    {
        _globalServiceFactory = globalServiceFactory;
    }

    public void UseService()
    {
        using (var service = _globalServiceFactory())
        {
            service.Value.DoWhatever();
            Console.WriteLine("service.instanceId = {0}\n", service.Value.instanceId);
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static ILifetimeScope rootScope;
    static ILifetimeScope globalServiceScope;
    static ILifetimeScope consumerScope;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<GlobalService>().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("globalServiceScope");
        builder.RegisterType<Consumer>().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("consumerScope");

        var container = builder.Build();
        this.rootScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope();
        this.globalServiceScope = rootScope.BeginLifetimeScope("globalServiceScope");
        this.consumerScope = globalServiceScope.BeginLifetimeScope("consumerScope");

        var consumer = consumerScope.Resolve<Consumer>();
        consumer.UseService(); // service.instanceId is 1
        ResetServiceScope();
        consumer.UseService(); // service.instanceId is 1, but I want it to be 2
    }

    static void ResetServiceScope()
    {
        globalServiceScope.Dispose();
        globalServiceScope = rootScope.BeginLifetimeScope("globalServiceScope");
    }
}
```

I want to achieve that the factory in `Consumer` always returns the current active `GlobalService` instance, whose lifetime is controlled somewhere else so that the `Consumer` does not need to know anything about how the `GlobalService` is reloaded.

I'm not sure if I actually misuse Autofac (or DI in general) hereby since I'm just beginning to use it (and DI in general). Regardless if I do misuse it or not, I'm kind of stuck here at the moment and would highly appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433983/autofac-any-way-to-resolve-the-innermost-scope

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work for me. As I understand DI, a component should not know anything about how it gets the resource it needs. It shouldn't even know about LifetimeScopes. Oversimplified the resource/service is either just there (passed in the ctor and ready to use) or it can be retrieved one (e.g. with a factory method passed in the ctor). Like saying "I'd like to have an instance of `GlobalService` that I can use. I don't care about how it is created or if the instance is the same I retrieved in the call before, let someone else handle that." Or am I wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you're misusing LifetimeScopes. Since `consumerScope` is created from `globalServiceScope`, when you dispose `globalServiceScope`, you are also disposing `consumerScope`. Technically, any service resolved from either scope shouldn't be accessible any longer. For example, if `Consumer` implemented `IDisposable`, it would be disposed when you dispose `globalServiceScope`.

I'm not sure what you're actually trying to accomplish, so I can't suggest a better way.

EDIT: So Alexander pointed out that I'm incorrect that the inner container is disposed when the outer container is disposed, but this is because of a known bug with no easy fix, not because it's valid behavior. If someone fixes the bug, the above usage breaks.

EDIT 2: I tweaked your code to introduce a `ReloadableSingleton` class, because I think that's what you're trying to achieve. I added some Debug.Assert code just to verify that it works. You could take this back out, obviously. You could eliminate the `Func<>` requirement in Consumer if you used an `IGlobalService` interface, and registered an implementation that defers each method call to the singleton, but I didn't feel like coding all of that in case this is off track. Does this help?

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

using Autofac;
using Autofac.Builder;

namespace Demo
{
    internal class GlobalService
    {
        private static int instanceCounter = 0;
        public int instanceId = ++instanceCounter;
        public void DoWhatever() {}
    }

    internal class Consumer
    {
        private readonly Func<GlobalService> _globalServiceFactory;

        public Consumer(Func<GlobalService> globalServiceFactory)
        {
            _globalServiceFactory = globalServiceFactory;
        }

        public int UseService()
        {
            var service = _globalServiceFactory();
            service.DoWhatever();
            Console.WriteLine("service.instanceId = {0}\n", service.instanceId);
            return service.instanceId;
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private const string ConsumerTag = "consumerScope";
        private const string GlobalServiceTag = "globalServiceScope";

        private static ILifetimeScope rootScope;
        private static ILifetimeScope globalServiceScope;
        private static ILifetimeScope consumerScope;

        private static void Main()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // root scope:
            builder.RegisterReloadableSingleton<GlobalService>();

            // global service scope:
            builder.RegisterType<GlobalService>().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(GlobalServiceTag);
            builder.RegisterSingletonReloader<GlobalService>().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(GlobalServiceTag);

            // consumer scope:
            builder.RegisterReloadableSingletonAccessor<GlobalService>().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(ConsumerTag);
            builder.RegisterType<Consumer>().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(ConsumerTag);

            using (var container = builder.Build())
            using (rootScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                ReloadGlobalService();

                consumerScope = rootScope.BeginLifetimeScope(ConsumerTag);
                var consumer = consumerScope.Resolve<Consumer>();

                Debug.Assert(consumer.UseService() == 1, "1");

                ReloadGlobalService();
                Debug.Assert(consumer.UseService() == 2, "2");

                consumerScope.Dispose();
                globalServiceScope.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private static void ReloadGlobalService()
        {
            if (globalServiceScope != null)
                globalServiceScope.Dispose();

            globalServiceScope = rootScope.BeginLifetimeScope(GlobalServiceTag);
            globalServiceScope.ReloadSingleon<GlobalService>();
        }
    }

    internal class ReloadableSingleton<T>
    {
        public T Instance { get; set; }
    }

    internal static class ReloadableSingletonExtensions
    {
        public static void ReloadSingleon<T>(this IComponentContext scope)
        {
            scope.ResolveKeyed<Action>("reloader:" + typeof(T))();
        }

        public static IRegistrationBuilder<ReloadableSingleton<T>, SimpleActivatorData, SingleRegistrationStyle>
            RegisterReloadableSingleton<T>(this ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.RegisterInstance(new ReloadableSingleton<T>()).SingleInstance();
        }

        public static IRegistrationBuilder<Func<T>, SimpleActivatorData, SingleRegistrationStyle>
            RegisterReloadableSingletonAccessor<T>(this ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.Register<Func<T>>(c =>
            {
                var singleton = c.Resolve<ReloadableSingleton<T>>();
                // It's important to register the func and not the instance directly. Otherwise you'd get the original
                // instance every time, even after the Instance has been modified.
                return () => singleton.Instance;
            });
        }

        public static IRegistrationBuilder<Action, SimpleActivatorData, SingleRegistrationStyle>
            RegisterSingletonReloader<T>(this ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.Register<Action>(c =>
            {
                var context = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
                return () =>
                {
                    var singleton = context.Resolve<ReloadableSingleton<T>>();
                    var newInstance = context.Resolve<T>();
                    singleton.Instance = newInstance;
                };
            })
                .Keyed<Action>("reloader:" + typeof (T));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "when you dispose globalServiceScope, you are also disposing consumerScope" - This's wrong, parent lifetimescope doesn't dispose chid one, see http://code.google.com/p/autofac/issues/detail?id=397

Comment: In [the documentation](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/DeterministicDisposal) it has been stated, that child scopes are NOT automatically disposed. But that's not my point, I'm sorry if I didn't make that clear. My aim is to make `Consumer` able to get the current instance of a resource without knowing how to update it. I don't want to use a global singleton or something like that since this would couple the `Consumer` to the providing class (I want to avoid using a service locator). I hoped, DI/Autofac could help me here, but if it does not, maybe someone knows another approach.

Comment: Ah yes. I'm seeing that now. But it appears it only works because they can't figure out how to fix the bug without lots of other problems. That doesn't make it valid behavior. I wouldn't rely on this behavior because if they figure out how to fix the bug, your app would break. For your situation then, do you intend GlobalService to be a singleton that you can replace, but there should only ever be one live instance? I'm still trying to understand?

Comment: Be that as it may, to me it's not important which scopes creates what instances. I'm looking for a technique that makes it possible for the `Consumer` to retrieve instances of services without having control over their lifetimes. I'm not bound to a specific pattern or framework here, using DI/Autofac was just a promising approach at the first glance and I'm using it successfully in other parts of the application. I'd appreciate avoiding patterns like service locator or an application-wide global static object and I like the concept behind DI/Autofac, so I hoped it could serve here too.

Comment: @Hannes EDIT 2 has a possible solution for you, if I understand your requirements correctly.

Comment: @Jim thanks a lot for your input. The solution you suggested would work just fine. However, in the meantime I've come across another solution which I consider more simple and straightforward (see my answer). I'd gladly appreciate your two cents on that one.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** In `ResetGlobalServiceInstance()`, removed `builder.Update(serviceContainer);` and added disposing and creating of a new container instance due to a memory leak (`Update()` does not destroy the previous `GlobalService` instance).

I just hit upon a solution that suits my needs and doesn't require adding additional management classes. All it takes is two separate `IContainer`s instead of one. This is the resulting code:

```cs
class GlobalService
{
    private static int instanceCounter = 0;
    public int instanceId = ++instanceCounter;
}

class Consumer
{
    private readonly Func<GlobalService> _globalServiceFactory;

    public Consumer(Func<GlobalService> globalServiceFactory)
    {
        _globalServiceFactory = globalServiceFactory;
    }

    public int UseService()
    {
        var service = _globalServiceFactory();
        return service.instanceId;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static IContainer consumerContainer;
    static IContainer serviceContainer;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var serviceBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
        serviceBuilder.RegisterType<GlobalService>().SingleInstance();
        serviceContainer = serviceBuilder.Build();

        var consumerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
        consumerBuilder.RegisterType<Consumer>();
        consumerBuilder.Register(c => serviceContainer.Resolve<GlobalService>());
        consumerContainer = consumerBuilder.Build();

        var consumer = consumerContainer.Resolve<Consumer>();
        int serviceId = consumer.UseService();
        Debug.Assert(serviceId == 1, "Call 1, instance 1");
        serviceId = consumer.UseService();
        Debug.Assert(serviceId == 1, "Call 2, still instance 1");
        ResetGlobalServiceInstance();
        serviceId = consumer.UseService();
        Debug.Assert(serviceId == 2, "Call 3, now instance 2");
        serviceId = consumer.UseService();
        Debug.Assert(serviceId == 2, "Call 4, still instance 2");
    }

    public static void ResetGlobalServiceInstance()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<GlobalService>().SingleInstance();
        builder.Dispose();
        serviceContainer = builder.Build();
    }
}
```

While this solves my problem for now, I'd appreciate feedback on potential issues, like having multiple `IContainer`s in one application or generally committing a major DI/Autofac misuse here.

Comment: There's a memory leak with this approach. When you Update the `serviceContainer`, it appends new registrations, but does not remove old ones. This means there's still a reference to the original instance of `GlobalService` living on in `serviceContainer`. You can see this if you add  `foreach (var gs in serviceContainer.Resolve<GlobalService[]>()) Console.WriteLine(gs.instanceId);` to the end of `Main` that you will see 2 and 1 returned. Instance 1 will continue to live until `serviceContainer` is disposed.

Comment: Indeed. Though replacing `builder.Update(serviceContainer);` with `serviceContainer.Dispose(); serviceContainer = builder.Build();` should remove the leak, doesn't it?